# Circular progress bar using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried a example given on jsfiddle about a circular progress bar with image within it and its working fine when I am trying on fiddle but its not working when I am doing the same on my system locally.

I am getting this error:

```
progressbar.js:2050 Uncaught Error: Container does not exist: #bar
    at Circle.Shape (progressbar.js:2050)
    at new Circle (progressbar.js:1674)
    at dummy.html:36
```

Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/master/dist/progressbar.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <style media="screen">
    svg {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }

    .wrapper {
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }

    .wrapper> #bar,
    .wrapper> img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .wrapper> img {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar', {
      strokeWidth: 3,
      color: '#000'

    });
    circle.animate(1);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://static.iltalehti.fi/terveys/kippari_etu2250612PP_tr.jpg" />
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code executes before `<div id="bar"></div>` exists in the DOM ... fix that ASAP - it works in jsfiddle because javascript is by default in `onload` - therefore the DOM is fully populated **before** code is run ASAP

Comment: @JaromandaX throwing shade before 10am.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - it's after 6pm here :p I guess that's before 10am tomorrow though

Comment: @JaromandaX hello timezones my old friend. (I'm in GMT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're trying to instantiate the plugin on the `#bar` element *before* it exists in the DOM. You need to move that code block to just before the `</body>` element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/master/dist/progressbar.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    svg {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
    .wrapper {
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    .wrapper > #bar,
    .wrapper > img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper > img {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://static.iltalehti.fi/terveys/kippari_etu2250612PP_tr.jpg" />
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#bar', {
      strokeWidth: 3,
      color: '#000'
    });
    circle.animate(1);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnx ,it was a silly mistake and I didnt figure out that.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <!--Live Demo & Tutorial foolishdeveloper.com -->
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-pie-chart/2.1.6/jquery.easypiechart.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
 <style>
   body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #0d0c2d;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 160px);
  grid-gap: 80px;
  background: #0d0c2d;
  box-shadow: -5px -5px 8px rgba(94, 104, 121, 0.288),
              4px 4px 6px rgba(94, 104, 121, 0.288);
  padding: 60px;
  margin: auto 0;
}

@media (min-width: 420px) and (max-width: 659px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 160px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 660px) and (max-width: 899px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 160px);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 160px);
  }
}

.container .box {
  width: 100%;
}

.container .box h2 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.container .box .chart {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  color: #fff;
}

.container .box canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="chart" data-percent="90" >90%</div>
    <h2>HTML</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="chart" data-percent="72" >72%</div>
    <h2>CSS</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="chart" data-percent="81" >81%</div>
    <h2>JAVASCRIPT</h2>
  </div>
 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $('.chart').easyPieChart({
    size: 160,
    barColor: "#36e617",
    scaleLength: 0,
    lineWidth: 15,
    trackColor: "#525151",
    lineCap: "circle",
    animate: 2000,
  });
});
</script>
</body>
<!--Live Demo & Tutorial foolishdeveloper.com -->
</html>
```

Comment: Even though there's an accepted answer, please add explanations into your answer.